# How to Display Translated Content by Language in Drupal Views?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Title: How to Display Translated Content by Language in Drupal Views?

I have a View in Drupal with multiple displays, each configured as follows:

**Display 1: Articles**

- FILTER CRITERIA:

  - Content: Published (= Yes)
  - Content: Content type (= Article)
- PAGE SETTINGS:

  - Path: /articles/insights

**Display 2: Page**

- FILTER CRITERIA:

  - Content: Published (= Yes)
  - Content: Content type (= Article)
  - Content: Page Category (= Glossary)
- PAGE SETTINGS:

  - Path: /articles/glossary

**Display 3: A-F**

- FILTER CRITERIA:

  - Content: Published (= Yes)
  - Content: Content type (= Article)
  - Content: Page Category (= Glossary)
  - Content: Subtitle (regex ^[A-Fa-f].*$)
- BLOCK SETTINGS:

  - Block name: None
  - Block category: Lists (Views)
  - Allow settings: Items per page

The first display, "Articles," with the path `/articles/insights`, shows the article listing, while the second, third, and other similar displays show the Glossary of articles. The Page Category is a field called `field_page_category`, which can be selected when adding an article.

Now, I have some articles that are translated into Portuguese-Brazil (pt-br) and have the page category as Glossary. I want to display these links when I access `/pt-br/articles/glossary`. I tried creating a new display for the View with the path `/pt-br/articles/glossary`, and in the filter criteria, I added:

- Content: Translation language (= Portuguese, Brazil)
- Content revision: Translation language (= Portuguese, Brazil)

However, it still displays all the links in English. I'm unable to find a Language filter when attempting to add it.

The SQL query I received is:

```
SELECT "node_field_data"."langcode" AS "node_field_data_langcode", "node__field_subtitle"."field_subtitle_value" AS "node__field_subtitle_field_subtitle_value", "node_field_data"."nid" AS "nid"
FROM
{node_field_data} "node_field_data"
INNER JOIN {node__field_page_category} "node__field_page_category" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_page_category.entity_id AND node__field_page_category.deleted = '0'
INNER JOIN {node_field_revision} "node_field_revision" ON node_field_data.vid = node_field_revision.vid
LEFT JOIN {node__field_subtitle} "node__field_subtitle" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_subtitle.entity_id AND (node__field_subtitle.deleted = '0' AND node__field_subtitle.langcode = node_field_data.langcode)
WHERE ((node__field_page_category.field_page_category_value = 'Glossary')) AND (("node_field_data"."status" = '1') AND ("node_field_data"."type" IN ('article')) AND ("node_field_data"."langcode" IN ('pt-br')) AND ("node_field_revision"."langcode" IN ('pt-br')))
ORDER BY "node__field_subtitle_field_subtitle_value" ASC
```

How can I configure Drupal Views to display content in Portuguese (pt-br) when accessing the `/pt-br/articles/glossary` URL? I can't seem to find the Language filter to achieve this.

The language filters I already have are as follows:

| Title | Category |
| --- | --- |
| Delivery Language | Content |
| Original language | Content |
| Translation language | Content |
| Translation source | Content |
| Original language | Content revision |
| Original language | Content revision |
| Translation language | Content revision |
| Translation source | Content revision |

Answer (score 0):

Happy Coder

Instead of these filters, could you add `Content: Default translation` filter and select `true`? and in the `Rendering Language` select `Interface text language selected for page`.

Regards,